# Android Studio - Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio worked normally and one day i started getting this message.

I tried reinstalling Android Studio and SDK multiple times, disabling firewall but nothing worked.
I dont know what should i tried also changing

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`

to
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
    This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
    For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
    Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
    Please read the following process output to find out more:
    -----------------------
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon
```

Comment: Try with latest Android Studio [from here] (https://developer.android.com/studio).
If not worked May be Your machine running on low memory.Could you please provide your System configuration  like RAM and CPU ?

Comment: Everything worked before but i had some problems with low memory on C: drive (i also thought thats the cause), but i cleared it and now i have 20GB free, but Android Studio is located on D: where i have 90GB free. Also i have Intel i-3 3.30Ghz  and 8GB RAM.

Comment: @АцаРусија Have you tried deleting the .gradle folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a git repo, please try a

`git stash` it keeps your changes for "later"

`git clean -xdf` It removes your repo from non-checked-in files.

After you have to reopen your project again.

The question come, where to do so. Here you can see it
[image]

Then you can type here

[image]

Comment: Where should i type that?

Comment: in terminal/shell

Comment: When i open terminal its empty, i cannot start new session nor anything, its just blank window https://imgur.com/a/JZuc81m

Comment: Then open a "real" shell, not in Android Studio. Independent of this, I would recommend starting from scratch. Remove all, delete all, install all ... repos is hopefully commited. Btw, do you have a link to repos, and I can verify

Answer (score 0):

This error may have various reasons

1. Install/verify latest compatible Gradle version with Android Studio.Or
2. Some time IDE run on low memory so then you need to increase org.gradle.jvmargs in gradle.properties file. Or
3. File->Invalidate Caches/Restart Android Studio.Or
4. Close project remove .gradle folder from project and open project again.

Comment: Could you  please provide Android Studio and Gradle version detail along with system configurations ?

Comment: I assume this is Grade version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'` and i have tried newer versions, and i have Android Studio 3.1.1 (also i tried 3.3 and some other versions too)

Comment: Update your Android Studio with latest one followed by gradle version.
Install AS when you have good internet connection so that AS can upgrade all the necessary plugins. Go to AndroidStudio->CheckForUpdate